# How to disable tracing in web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, trace

[image: Tracing I am seeing][image]I have created a Web API project in VS 2013. Where the Tracing is enabled by default. How can I disable it?

I tried few things in webapi.config, but didn't work out.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the line  `config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();` that is probably in your WebApiConfig file.

Comment: No..that was not there at all. Since my application is MVC5 ..WEB API2..tracing is by default enabled.

Comment: @KokiralaSudheer I don't think so.  As far as I know nothing changed in tracing in WebAPI2.  The nuget is still here https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Tracing/

Comment: @KokiralaSudheer How are you seeing tracing output?

Comment: I can see the tracing in the output window without installing nuget package or setting any thing in the webapi.config.

Comment: @KokiralaSudheer I can find nothing new about tracing in the Web API 2/2.1 release notes. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/releases/whats-new-in-aspnet-web-api-21  Can you show your config?

Comment: see the updated question above. Did u checked Web API Project Template in VS 2013? As per this sentance...."If you have installed the
tooling refresh of Visual Studio 2012 ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2, tracing is enabled by default when you create your
project from Web API project template." it is enabled by default

Comment: @KokiralaSudheer I created a Web API template and the tracing was not enabled for me.  I have no idea how they magically enable tracing without installing an implementation of ITraceWriter.

Comment: Are you sure you are seeing Web API traces? Can you share a sample of what you are seeing traced?

Comment: @Darrel I am using VS 2013 with MVC 5 WEB API Tracing. Did u tried in VS2013 (Web API 2) ?

Comment: @Yishai...yes I am using Web API traces

Comment: @KokiralaSudheer Yes.  I tried it with VS2013 and the web tooling installed.  Can you show an example of the trace that you are seeing?

Comment: @KokiralaSudheer  That's not WebApi tracing.

Answer (score 0):

In general, we can enable and disable tracing in web.config file, under system.web section.

```
<System.web>
<trace enabled="false" />
```

Hope this will be helpful.